# How to fetch Distinct Title from the GROUP_CONCAT as Left Join without repeating other tables' data?

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a table of values something like this:

```
TABLE:     prop_feat
TYPE       FEAT
Appliances Gas Range
Appliances Fridge
Interior   Hardwood Flooring
```

I'm trying to display the Type once with the features below:

#### Appliances

Gas Range, Fridge

#### Interior

Hardwood Flooring

These are values that could be empty so I need to LEFT JOIN this table. I've searched everywhere! How should I be writing MySQL to display results like this? This is what I have so far which isn't quite doing it. (I know.. not LEFT JOIN.. )

```
SELECT *
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT ('', type, '', prop_feat.feat, '') 
   ORDER BY type ASC SEPARATOR ' '  )
FROM prop_feat
WHERE prop_feat.id_prop = '$page'  )  AS feat
FROM properties
WHERE id_pg = '$page'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

This is my whole query.. I've got a whole bunch of joins. Which is making the type/feature issue difficult.

```
SELECT *,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<tr><td>', style, '</td><td>', beds, '</td><td>', ba, '</td><td>', sq_ft, '</td><td>', rent, '</td><td>', dep, '</td></tr>') 
    ORDER BY beds DESC SEPARATOR '') AS unit, 
(SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT ('<h4>', type, '</h4><div>', prop_feat.feat, '</div>') 
        ORDER BY type ASC SEPARATOR ' '  )
    FROM prop_feat
    WHERE prop_feat.id_prop = '$page'  )  AS interior 
FROM properties 
INNER JOIN prop_units ON prop_units.id_prop = '$page'
LEFT JOIN prop_intro ON prop_intro.id_prop = '$page'  
LEFT JOIN prop_hours ON prop_hours.id_prop = '$page'  
WHERE id_pg = '$page'
GROUP BY type
```

Properties has: name, address, city, prov, postcode, phone (display one property - basic info)
Prop_units has: beds, bath, square feet, rent, deposit, style
Prop_intro: title, text (description of place)
Prop_hours: Sunfrom, Sunto, MonFrom, MonTo, etc (times open during week)
Prop_feat: Property features like has Hardwood Flooring, need to sort by Type and display type only once.. if possible!

EDIT EDIT - NOW USING THIS INSTEAD

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT *,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<tr><td>', style, '</td><td>', beds, '</td><td>', ba, '</td><td>', sq_ft, '</td><td>$', rent, '</td><td>',IF(dep='','','$'), dep, '</td></tr>') 
    ORDER BY u_order ASC SEPARATOR '') AS unit
FROM properties 
INNER JOIN prop_units ON prop_units.id_prop = '$page'
LEFT JOIN prop_intro ON prop_intro.id_prop = '$page'  
LEFT JOIN prop_hours ON prop_hours.id_prop = '$page'  
WHERE id_pg = '$page'"));

$check = mysql_query("SELECT type, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<tr><td>', feat, '</td></tr>') SEPARATOR '') AS featlist
FROM prop_feat
WHERE id_prop = '$page'
GROUP BY type");
```

Comment: What are the columns in table `properties`?

Comment: Your prop_feat table sample refers to `TITLE`, but your query refers to `type` - which is correct? Also, do you want a separate row for each type/title of features (as indicated in your sample output), or a single row combining all types and features for the property (as implied by the structure of your sample query)?

Comment: Type is correct. I'm just using type as a title.

Comment: Okay I realized I simplified this too much! These queries work but loop some other outputs as well.. But I didn't include them so you'd never know! Woops... let me edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` clause because `GROUP_CONCAT()` is an aggregate function.

```
SELECT  Title, GROUP_CONCAT(FEAT) FeatList
FROM    Prop_Feat
GROUP   BY Title
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/246c7/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║   TITLE    ║     FEATLIST      ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ Appliances ║ Gas Range,Fridge  ║
║ Interior   ║ Hardwood Flooring ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks for the example on SQLFiddle.. first time seeing this website. I've done 2 queries to accomplish this in the end. Your example worked well.

Comment: what are your queries? maybe we can find ways to combined it `:D`

Comment: Well now I have two queries like this (which work fine but maybe not optimal)

Comment: maybe you can open another question on this so many users can view it. anyway, what is the result when you add explain in the query, eg `EXPLAIN SELECT...you select statement`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT p.*, f.title, group_concat(distinct f.feat) features
FROM properties p
left join prop_feat f on p.id_pg = f.id_prop
WHERE p.id_pg = '$page'
group by f.title
order by f.title
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Looks like I can't do one query for what I want to accomplish! I'll remember how to structure LEFT JOINS using your example though ;)